# Why is library not being attached to my email twig template?

Tags: 8, theming, commerce

I am overriding the commerce-order-receipt.html.twig by adding that file to mytheme/templates/commerce. I then add these lines to mytheme.libraries.yml

```
email:
  css:
    base:
      assets/css/email.css: {}
```

in mytheme.info.yml i add:

```
libraries:
  - mytheme/email
```

and then at the top of my twig tpl i add this:

```
{{ attach_library('mytheme/email') }}
```

but email that is sent does not have email.css attached.

Am i still missing something?

Comment: Because for e-mails its bad practice, [Using CSS in HTML emails](https://kb.benchmarkemail.com/using-css-in-html-emails/)

Comment: Thanks, i had given up on attaching a library and got it working with an ext style sheet (link tag); but from your article, it sounds like that may not be reliable. We'll stick with inline styles. Unfortunate that the Drupal twig doc doesn't mention this (or perhaps I am still attaching incorrectly).

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to add the placeholders in your twig template too:

```
<css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
<js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
```

See here for the placeholder tokens: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/8.2.x

Be aware that this will load all libraries for the request and bloat up your email with a lot of (unwanted) css and js.

> I strongly recommend to use inline CSS for you email template.

Comment: I've been going by this guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme and no mention of placeholder tokens. But i added the line you mentioned to twig tpl as well as the matching code to mytheme.theme's preprocess_html - no change.